# Mostrar hintText en SearchView - Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

Tengo un Layout para buscar archivos, el layout contiene una barra de busqueda (SearchView) y un RecyclerView.

```
<SearchView
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"                
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/TxtSearchB"                
                android:searchIcon="@mipmap/lupa03"
                android:goIcon="@mipmap/lupa03"
                android:background="@drawable/ftb"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:queryHint="Id o Nombre..."
                />
```

Adjunto imagen:

[image: Barra]

El problema que necesito resolver es que actualmente para poder buscar algo se hace de la siguiente forma:

> 1. Click en lupa de `Layout Inicio` para abrir `Layout Búsqueda`.
> 2. En `layout búsqueda` se necesita dar click en la lupa de la parte izquierda de barra (foto).
> 3. Y hasta después muestra el `hintText` y permite escribir algo en el `SearchView`.

**¿Como puedo hacer que en cuanto se inicie el Layout muestre el `hintText` y permita escribir para omitir el paso #2?**

Ya intente quitando el parámetro de `searchIcon` pero lo que hace simplemente es cambiar mi icono personalizado por uno por defecto (una lupa mas fea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inténtalo de esta forma:

```
var vSearchView = FindViewById<Android.Widget.SearchView>(Resource.Id.TxtSearchB);
vSearchView.SetIconifiedByDefault(false);
vSearchView.RequestFocus();
```

Comment: Hola @Jorge.Mendez, **te sugiero revisar acerca de Sock Puppets**:
[¿Por qué me quitaron puntos de reputación?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/por-qu%c3%a9-me-quitaron-400-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n/3196#3196)
[¿Cómo deben gestionarse las cuentas títere en Stack Exchange?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%c3%b3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%c3%adtere-en-stack-exchange)